# Remove white spaces and new lines in ArrayList

Tags: java, list, selenium-webdriver, arraylist, split

I have an ArrayList which need to be compared later. The problem is how to make it pretty? The list is getting form menu elements.

Or can I assert words only? I use Java, Thanks.

I tried this using Java and Selenium WebDriver:

```java
String text = list.get(i).getText();
      text.replaceAll("^[.,\\s]+", "").split("[.,\\s]+");
```

ArrayList that I have printed like:

```
[Menu, General \n
      Export \n
            Layer Manager, Reporting \n
Theme \n
      Preferences \n
            Labels \n
            Reset Defaults \n
      Report]
```

Expected result:

```
[Menu, General, Export, Layer Manager, Reporting, Theme, Preferences, Labels, Reset Defaults, Report]
```

Comment: Do you want to create a new array with every value splitted (so that you can iterate over each one) or just to change the output to the one you gave ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For removing whitespaces, we can use trim() and to remove newline character we need to replace,

```
list.stream().map(s -> s.replaceAll("\n",",").trim()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
text.replaceAll("\\n", ",");
```

This would replace `\n` with `,` and give output as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you have got a *List* with 2 elements as:

```
[Menu, General \n Export \n Layer Manager, Reporting \n Theme \n Preferences \n Labels \n Reset Defaults \n Report]
```

Presumably through this line of code:

```
String text = list.get(i).getText();
```

You are tring to get the second element and print the words as a *List*. So first you need to convert the string `General \n Export \n Layer Manager, Reporting \n Theme \n Preferences \n Labels \n Reset Defaults \n Report` into a *Array* removing the **`\n`** and then `split()`ing them. You can use the following solution:

- Code:

  ```
  String text = list.get(i).getText();
  //String text = "General \n Export \n Layer Manager, Reporting \n Theme \n Preferences \n Labels \n Reset Defaults \n Report";
  String newText = text.replace(" \n "," ");
  String strArray[] = newText.split(" ");
  System.out.println("Output as Array List");
  for(int i=0; i < strArray.length; i++){
      System.out.println(strArray[i]);
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  General
  Export
  Layer
  Manager,
  Reporting
  Theme
  Preferences
  Labels
  Reset
  Defaults
  Report
  ```

Now, you can easily convert the *Array* into an *List* to get the desired output using the following solution:

- Code:

  ```
  List<String>myList = new ArrayList<>();
  myList = Arrays.asList(strArray);
  System.out.println("Output as List");
  System.out.println(myList);
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Output as List
  [General, Export, Layer, Manager,, Reporting, Theme, Preferences, Labels, Reset, Defaults, Report]
  ```

Answer (score -1):

If you do the enters with

```
String enter = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

Then I belive you can just split at enter. It makes it easier I guess.